# Difference between DIR /S and Get-ChildItem -Recurse

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe

Why do these commands return different results?

From cmd.exe:

```
>DIR /S C:\SVN
...
     Total Files Listed:
           87268 File(s) 23,080,818,153 bytes
           15836 Dir(s)  216,886,992,896 bytes free
```

From powershell.exe:

```
>Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Force -Path 'C:\SVN' |
    Measure-Object -Sum -Property Length |
    Select-Object -Property Count,Sum

Count         Sum
-----         ---
87305 23081499113
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you issue a DIR command in a CMD prompt, the default behavior is to NOT
to show System and Hidden files.
To show everything, use the `/A` switch without any modifiers.

However, in PowerShell you have used the `-Force` parameter, which is defined as
"Allows the cmdlet to get items that cannot otherwise not be accessed by the user, such as hidden or system files".

So this difference means that you have some hidden or system files in your folder.

Comment: Thank you. I was already using `-Force` for PowerShell, so it was already getting the "hidden" files. The `DIR` command was not without `/A`.